# Query language in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

How do I select from a table by another unique column other than id
im looking a replacement for

```
     String fbid=<some facebookId>
     User user = User.findBy("facebookId",fbid).first();
```

I'm using `Java` + `Ebean` and not scala!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User user = User.find.where().eq("facebookId", fbid).findUnique();
```

Of course you can create a 'shortcut' by adding a method into your `User` model:

```
public static User findByFacebookId(String fbid){
    return find.where().eq("facebookId", fbid).findUnique();
}
```

and using it in controller:

```
User user = User.findByFacebookId(fbid);
```

It's pretty good solution as you can keep your controllers' code clean and use custom `finders` as sophisticated as required at the case.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing the same thing, i was looking for a shortcut.